# Visual Studio Code with sftp plugin upload ignored .git folder and .gitignore file

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

I have this `sftp.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "projectname",
    "remotePath": "/htdocs/",
    "host": "myhostdomain",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "passive": true,
    "watcher": {
        "files": "**/*",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "ignore": [
            ".vscode",
            ".git",
            ".gitignore",
            "config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's really ignore the `.vscode` folder and `config.php` file, but not the `.git` and `.gitignore`

How can I fix this? The .git folder's changes generate massive network usage.

Comment: The `ignore` block of code should be outside `watcher` as a separate option.Also, look for the path of `.git` and`.gitignore` relative to the context of your current config.

Answer (score 5):

It's been three years since this question and I'm not sure if anyone still needs this answer.

Since I also fell into the same trap, leaving a possible solution here hoping it helps others. :)

[According to the project's wiki page on github](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/wiki/Config#remoteexplorerfilesexclude)

The developer has updated setting field name, So your sftp settings need to be changed to

```
{
    "name": "projectname",
    "remotePath": "/htdocs/",
    "host": "myhostdomain",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "passive": true,
    "watcher": {
        "files": "**/*",
        "autoUpload": true,
    },
    "remoteExplorer": {
        "filesExclude": [
            ".vscode",
            ".git",
            ".gitignore",
            "config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried this, and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The following configuration is valid for me:

```
{
    "name": "My Server",
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        ".gitignore"
    ]
}
```