# VS Code, SFTP extension by Natizyskunk, cannot exclude folder from upload

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the VS Code SFTP extension by Natizyskunk, and it's configured like this:

```
[{
  "name": "host_name",
  "host": "host_address",
  "protocol": "sftp",
  "privateKeyPath": "local_key_path",
  "port": 22,
  "username": "user_name",
  "remotePath": "remote_path_to _sync",
  "uploadOnSave": false,
  "downloadOnOpen": true,
  "remoteExplorer": {
    "filesExclude": [
        "./data",
        "./data/*"
    ]},
  "watcher": {
      "files": "**/*",
      "autoUpload": true,
      "autoDelete": true
    },
  "useTempFile": false,
  "openSsh": false
}]
```

As you can see, I'm using

```
"downloadOnOpen": true
```

and the watcher args, so that basically every time I modify something on the local machine it's uploaded on the remote, and viceversa when I modify remote files they're updated on the local.

I want to exclude the "data" folder from this, so I tried adding both the remoteExplorer field as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296328/visual-studio-code-with-sftp-plugin-upload-ignored-git-folder-and-gitignore-fi), and the "ignore" part (as suggested pretty much everywhere), but it's not working...every time I make changes in /data (I tried creating dummy empty files), they are reflected on the remote. I assume there are some conflicting parts of the configuration file, how can I fix this?